# Java / Android loop - randomized data to assign to a button in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm building a variation of an quiz app for Android (so in Java). I have quiz question and a list of four quiz answers A, B, C and D.

I want to randomize the possible answers (A, B, C and D) so that if the user encounters the same question more than once they won't necessarily see the answer options in the same order.

The code below works by randomizing the order (for example to DACB). It then looks for A and assigns it to one of the four buttons depending on where it is found in the array (in this case it's in second position so it gets assigned to button B). The same approach is repeated for B, C and D. This works but isn't particularly elegant or efficient. There must be a more concise way...?

```
ArrayList<String>  mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
mylist.add("A");
mylist.add("B");
mylist.add("C");
mylist.add("D");
Collections.shuffle(mylist);
final int index=Ints.indexOf(mylist, "A");
if (index==0) {
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
} else if (index==1){
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
} else if (index==2){
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
} else if (index==3){
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
}

final int index=Ints.indexOf(mylist, "B");
if (index==0) {
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
} else if (index==1){
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
} else if (index==2){
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonC); 
} else if (index==3){
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
}

final int index=Ints.indexOf(mylist, "C");
if (index==0) {
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
} else if (index==1){
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
} else if (index==2){
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.buttonC); 
} else if (index==3){
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
}

final int index=Ints.indexOf(mylist, "D");
if (index==0) {
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
} else if (index==1){
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
} else if (index==2){
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.buttonC); 
} else if (index==3){
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get your buttons with `findViewById` every time you need to set text to it. It's less efficient. Collect your buttons into `ArrayList` so they would be in a required order (A,B,C,D), called `buttons` for example. And then get required button based on an index of your answer.

```
Collections.shuffle(mylist);

ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonA));
buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonB));
buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonC));
buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonD));

final int index=Ints.indexOf(mylist, "A");
button1 = buttons.get(index)

// Do the rest!
```